# Stopping dask-ssh created scheduler from the Client interface

Tags: dask

I am running Dask on a SLURM-managed cluster.

```
dask-ssh --nprocs 2 --nthreads 1 --scheduler-port 8786 --log-directory `pwd` --hostfile hostfile.$JOBID &
sleep 10

# We need to tell dask Client (inside python) where the scheduler is running
scheduler="`hostname`:8786"
echo "Scheduler is running at ${scheduler}"
export ARL_DASK_SCHEDULER=${scheduler}

echo "About to execute $CMD"

eval $CMD

# Wait for dash-ssh to be shutdown from the python
wait %1
```

I create a Client inside my python code and then when finished, I shut it down.

```
c=Client(scheduler_id)
...
c.shutdown()
```

My reading of the dask-ssh help is that the shutdown will shutdown all workers and then the scheduler. But it does not stop the background dask-ssh and so eventually the job timeouts.

I've tried this interactively in the shell. I cannot see how to stop the scheduler.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 4):

#### Recommendation with --scheduler-file

First, when setting up with SLURM you might consider using the `--scheduler-file` option, which allows you to coordinate the scheduler address using your NFS (which I assume you have given that you're using SLURM).  Recommend reading this doc section: http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#using-a-shared-network-file-system-and-a-job-scheduler

```
dask-scheduler --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json
dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json
dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json

>>> client = Client(scheduler_file='/path/to/scheduler.json')
```

Given this it also becomes easier to use the sbatch or qsub command directly.  Here is an example with SGE's qsub

```
# Start a dask-scheduler somewhere and write connection information to file
qsub -b y /path/to/dask-scheduler --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json

# Start 100 dask-worker processes in an array job pointing to the same file
qsub -b y -t 1-100 /path/to/dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/scheduler.json
```

#### Client.shutdown

It looks like client.shutdown only shuts down the client.  You're correct that this is inconsistent with the docstring.  I've raised an issue here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1085 for tracking further developments.

#### In the meantime

These three commands should suffice to tear down the workers, close the scheduler, and stop the scheduler process

```
client.loop.add_callback(client.scheduler.retire_workers, close_workers=True)
client.loop.add_callback(client.scheduler.terminate)
client.run_on_scheduler(lambda dask_scheduler: dask_scheduler.loop.stop())
```

#### What people usually do

Typically people start and stop clusters with whatever means that they started them.  This might involve using SLURM's kill command.  We should make the client-focused way more consistent though regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. The workaround does indeed work and is nicer than my use of psutil to send a SIGHUP. It's early days for my testing so I will probably invest time in driving slurm in a more intelligent way.

Comment: Very impressed with Dask by the way. I'm making use of delayed to create  graphs for quite complex radio astronomy processing.

Comment: Glad to hear it @TimCornwell .  The project currently needs people to write about their experiences.  Publicly documenting non-toy uses of dask.delayed is really quite valuable if you're up for it.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'll check with the responsible people on my side.

Comment: The "in the meantime" solution fails for me. The third line throws a `CommClosedError` from deep inside `distributed.core`, and the scheduler is still running. Is this solution no longer valid?